# Save image picked with FileOpenPicker

Tags: uwp, windows-10-mobile

I want to create an app where the user can select multiple images from its local photo storage and I want to load this photos into the app. The user must be able to find them every time he open the app. I used the `FileOpenPicker` to let the user selecting the photos with the **PickMultipleFilesAsync()** method. Now I don't know how can I save the photos to show them to the user next time he opens the app.

This is my code:

```
private async void AddButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
    openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
    openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".bmp");
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
    IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files = await openPicker.PickMultipleFilesAsync();
    if (files.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (StorageFile file in files)
        {
            BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            bitmapImage.DecodePixelHeight = 332;
            bitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth = 200;
            IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
            await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(stream);
            Wallpapers.Add(bitmapImage);
            stream.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to remember the location of where the photos were saved (or photos were copied from -- doesn't really matter). You have to make use of the Settings service.

You can save info like file path using the `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values` settings dictionary for later recall.

For example:
`Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["PhotosPath"] = file.Path;`

where file is StorageFile object as shown in your code, and next time you retrieve `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["PhotosPath"]` to initialize your file object with the Path.

You can shorten the above code line by instead declaring `using Windows.Storage;` namespace (which I think you already did for StorageFile) and just use 
`ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["PhotosPath"]` part in your code.

**Further advice:** If you're using [T10 Template](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/wiki) in your project, you wouldn't want to use Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values for settings directly. T10 has a more comprehensive settings service built upon Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current in the **Minimal Template** (as opposed to the alternative **Blank Template**) and that's what you'd want to use instead.

Comment: Instead of copying only the path, you can also copy the whole images (for the case that the photo directory doesn't exists anymore)
Like this:
Saving:  
`await file.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);`     Loading  
`IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFilesAsync();`

Comment: Thank you It was exactly what I was looking for